# Send Logs Arcsight Logger via C#

Tags: c#, arcsight

I want to send logs to ArcSight - Logger via C#.

While searching on google, found one interesting article [Check devices are not logged in ArcSight Logger via C# - Hakan Ungan](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/check-devices-logged-arcsight-logger-hakan-ungan/).

I have spent a couple of hours to search "How to send logs to ArcSight Logger" via C# but can't find any appropriate solutions.

Please someone can guide me how to send logs to ArcSight Logger via C#.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you are writing an application and just want to send the application logs to arcsight, and application is write in C#. If it's not, you just want to send some logs to ArcSight via C#.

So, the quickly question is: you need to send logs to ArcSight (Logger or ESM) through SmartConnector (or Flex). So basically in C# you need to write the logs to a file and "CEF compliant" to use a SmartConnector, or write logs whatever you want and create a regex parser to use FlexConnector.

You can as well send the logs directly via C# using syslog, but you will need a connector or activate the logger udp/tcp receiver.